# Serverless Contact form issue html css ajax js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, forms

So, I have this contact form sending me a mail and updating my google sheet. I found this on [GitHub](https://github.com/dwyl/learn-to-send-email-via-google-script-html-no-server). When I don't add the JS file I get a mail and an update. When I add the JS I get neither. I have tried with and without this script link when using JS but it does not work.

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

For security purpose I have removed my google sheet link and kept it as  `action="#"` from form and because I have added my e-mail in my google sheet I can leave my  `data-email=""` as it is.

I also don't get the thankyou message at the submission of the form when I have added my JS file, but without it I get confirmation displaying the details submitted.
There is a honeypot input label that is hidden by CSS and needs to be left blank for the form to be submitted successfully, avoiding spam.

It seems that there is some issue with the JS(duh!).
Please help!!!

***HTML***

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="contact form example">
  <title>Contact Form Example</title>

</head>

<body>
  <h2 class="content-head is-center">Contact Us!</h2>
  <aside>
       <p>
           We would <em>love</em> to hear from you! </p>
           <p>Please use the <b><em>Contact Form</em></b>
           to send us a message.
       </p>
   </aside>

<!-- START HERE -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.0/build/pure-min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   <!-- Style The Contact Form How Ever You Prefer -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <form class="gform pure-form pure-form-stacked" method="POST" data-email=""
  action="#">
    <!-- change the form action to your script url -->

    <div class="form-elements">
      <fieldset class="pure-group">
        <label for="name">Name: </label>
        <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="What your Mom calls you" />
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset class="pure-group">
        <label for="message">Message: </label>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="10"
        placeholder="Tell us what's on your mind..."></textarea>
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset class="pure-group">
        <label for="email"><em>Your</em> Email Address:</label>
        <input id="email" name="email" type="email" value=""
        required placeholder="your.name@email.com"/>
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset class="pure-group">
        <label for="color">Favourite Color: </label>
        <input id="color" name="color" placeholder="green" />
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset class="pure-group honeypot-field">
        <label for="honeypot">To help avoid spam, utilize a Honeypot technique with a hidden text field; must be empty to submit the form! Otherwise, we assume the user is a spam bot.</label>
        <input id="honeypot" type="text" name="honeypot" value="" />
      </fieldset>

      <button class="button-success pure-button button-xlarge">
        <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>&nbsp;Send</button>
    </div>

    <!-- Customise the Thankyou Message People See when they submit the form: -->
    <div class="thankyou_message" style="display:none;">
      <h2><em>Thanks</em> for contacting us!
        We will get back to you soon!</h2>
    </div>

  </form>

  <!-- Submit the Form to Google Using "AJAX" -->
  <script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src="form-submission-handler.js"></script>
<!-- END -->

</body>
</html>
```

***JS***

```
(function() {
  // get all data in form and return object
  function getFormData(form) {
    var elements = form.elements;
    var honeypot;

    var fields = Object.keys(elements).filter(function(k) {
      if (elements[k].name === "honeypot") {
        honeypot = elements[k].value;
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }).map(function(k) {
      if(elements[k].name !== undefined) {
        return elements[k].name;
      // special case for Edge's html collection
      }else if(elements[k].length > 0){
        return elements[k].item(0).name;
      }
    }).filter(function(item, pos, self) {
      return self.indexOf(item) == pos && item;
    });

    var formData = {};
    fields.forEach(function(name){
      var element = elements[name];
      
      // singular form elements just have one value
      formData[name] = element.value;

      // when our element has multiple items, get their values
      if (element.length) {
        var data = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
          var item = element.item(i);
          if (item.checked || item.selected) {
            data.push(item.value);
          }
        }
        formData[name] = data.join(', ');
      }
    });

    // add form-specific values into the data
    formData.formDataNameOrder = JSON.stringify(fields);
    formData.formGoogleSheetName = form.dataset.sheet || "responses"; // default sheet name
    formData.formGoogleSendEmail
      = form.dataset.email || ""; // no email by default

    return {data: formData, honeypot: honeypot};
  }

  function handleFormSubmit(event) {  // handles form submit without any jquery
    event.preventDefault();           // we are submitting via xhr below
    var form = event.target;
    var formData = getFormData(form);
    var data = formData.data;

    // If a honeypot field is filled, assume it was done so by a spam bot.
    if (formData.honeypot) {
      return false;
    }

    disableAllButtons(form);
    var url = form.action;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', url);
    // xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
          form.reset();
          var formElements = form.querySelector(".form-elements")
          if (formElements) {
            formElements.style.display = "none"; // hide form
          }
          var thankYouMessage = form.querySelector(".thankyou_message");
          if (thankYouMessage) {
            thankYouMessage.style.display = "block";
          }
        }
    };
    // url encode form data for sending as post data
    var encoded = Object.keys(data).map(function(k) {
        return encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[k]);
    }).join('&');
    xhr.send(encoded);
  }
  
  function loaded() {
    // bind to the submit event of our form
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll("form.gform");
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
      forms[i].addEventListener("submit", handleFormSubmit, false);
    }
  };
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", loaded, false);

  function disableAllButtons(form) {
    var buttons = form.querySelectorAll("button");
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      buttons[i].disabled = true;
    }
  }
})();
```

***CSS***

```
body {
  margin: 2em;
}
aside {
    background: #1f8dd6; /* same color as selected state on site menu */
    padding: 0.3em 1em;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
.content-head {
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  margin: 2em 0 1em;
}
.is-center {
  text-align: center;
}
.button-success {
  color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: rgb(28, 184, 65); /* this is a green */
}
.button-xlarge {
  font-size: 125%;
}
button {
  float: right;
}
#name, #email {
  width: 50%;
}
.honeypot-field {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: So if you do not include the jquery-3.3.1.min.js, everything is alright ?

Comment: If I remove my ```form-submission-handler.js``` from my folder, everything is fine. With or without 3.3.1.min.js my javascript does not work. @KenLee

Comment: Check the browser console to ensure no javascript errors are logging.

Comment: @PaulT anything else ?? The code seems right?

Comment: @PaulT. I get a 
```Access to XMLHttpRequest at '#' from origin 'https://epic-roentgen-925a77.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.```
 and 
```POST  net::ERR_FAILED handleFormSubmit @ form-submission-handler.js:87```
 first one pointing at my google sheet macro link. Any help?

Comment: There's a comment in the html that has: `change the form action to your script url`. I'm not sure what you need there?

Comment: Looks like the same [github resource](https://github.com/dwyl/learn-to-send-email-via-google-script-html-no-server/issues/358) has some info about the CORS.

Comment: @PaulT. Didn't help